# How does AWS Lambda execute a function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two functions in AWS Lambda, shown below. The first one agregates the data for every hour and returns the averages. The second performs matrix multiplications.

When I run these functions locally, the one performing matrix multiplications is fifty times slower, as it has to do a deal more operations than the one calculating hourly averages. When I run them on AWS Lambda, however, the function performing matrix multiplications is faster, sometimes even twice as fast. How can that be?

This is the importer calculating the hourly averages:

```
import json
import time


def get_averages(event, context):
    """
    file is a JSON object containing sensor data for a whole day. 
    Retrieves
        data from input, transforms it and stores it in another JSON 
        object.
    Input file:
        json = [{
            "sensor_id": row[0],
            "sensor_type": row[1],
            "lat": row[3], lon: row[4],
            "timestamp": row[5],
            "P1": row[6], "durP1": row[7], "ratioP1": row[8],
            "P2": row[9], "durP2": row[10], "ratioP2": row[11]
        }]

    Output object (data aggregated by hour):
        data = {
            "sensor_id": 1,
            "sensor_type": "ABC",
            "location": [lat, lon]
            "date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
            "total_data-points": int,
            "data": [
                        {
                            "time": "hh:mm:ss",
                            "data-points": int,
                            "P1": [1, 2, 3],  # ([avg_val, avg_dur, avg_ratio])
                            "P2": [1, 2, 3],  # ([avg_val, avg_dur, avg_ratio])
                        },
                    ]
        }
    """
    start = time.perf_counter()
    first_row = True
    for row in json.loads(event['json_input'].replace('\'', '"')):
        # row[5][11:-6] to remove day and '+00'
        if (first_row):
            out = {
                'sensor_id': row['sensor_id'],
                'sensor_type': row['sensor_type'],
                'location': [row['lat'], row['lon']],
                'date': row['timestamp'][:10],
                "total_data-points": 0,
                'data': [{'hour': row['timestamp'][11:13]}]
            }
            p1 = ([0, 0, 0], 0)  # second element of the tuple counts
            p2 = ([0, 0, 0], 0)  # data points per hour
            first_row = False

        elif (row['timestamp'][11:13] != out['data'][-1]['hour']):
            # calculate averages
            avg_p1 = [x / p1[1] for x in p1[0]]
            avg_p2 = [y / p1[1] for y in p2[0]]

            # append averages and number of data points
            out['total_data-points'] += p1[1]
            out['data'][-1]['data-points'] = p1[1]
            out['data'][-1]['P1'] = avg_p1
            out['data'][-1]['P2'] = avg_p2

            # add object for new hour, reset p1, p2
            out['data'].append({'hour': row['timestamp'][11:13]})
            p1 = ([0, 0, 0], 0)
            p2 = ([0, 0, 0], 0)

        # add values to p1, p2, increment counters
        data_1 = [float(x) for x in [row['P1'], row['durP1'],
                  row['ratioP1']]]
        data_2 = [float(y) for y in [row['P2'], row['durP2'],
                  row['ratioP2']]]
        p1 = ([sum(x) for x in zip(p1[0], data_1)], p1[1] + 1)
        p2 = ([sum(x) for x in zip(p1[0], data_2)], p2[1] + 1)

    # add last elements to the json object when EOF is reached
    avg_p1 = [x / p1[1] for x in p1[0]]
    avg_p2 = [y / p1[1] for y in p2[0]]

    out['total_data-points'] += p1[1]
    out['data'][-1]['data-points'] = p1[1]
    out['data'][-1]['P1'] = avg_p1
    out['data'][-1]['P2'] = avg_p2

    perf = time.perf_counter() - start

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({"output": out, "time": perf})
    }
```

This is the function performing matrix multiplications:

```
import json
import time


def get_matrix(event, context):
    """
    file is a JSON object containing sensor data for a whole day. 
    Retrieves
        data from input, transforms it and stores it in another JSON 
    object.
    Input file:
        json = [{
            "sensor_id": row[0],
            "sensor_type": row[1],
            "lat": row[3], lon: row[4],
            "timestamp": row[5],
            "P1": row[6], "durP1": row[7], "ratioP1": row[8],
            "P2": row[9], "durP2": row[10], "ratioP2": row[11]
        }]

    Output object:
        data = {
            "sensor_id": 1,
            "sensor_type": "ABC",
            "location": [lat, lon]
            "date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
            "data": [
                        {
                            "start_time": "hh:mm:ss",
                            "end_time": "hh:mm:ss",
                            "result": 2D-array
                        },
                    ]
        }
    """
    start = time.perf_counter()
    first_row = True
    cnt_rows = 0
    cnt_cols = 0
    matrix = [[]]
    for row in json.loads(event['json_input'].replace('\'', '"')):
        # row[5][11:-6] to remove day and '+00'
        if (first_row):
            out = {
                'sensor_id': row['sensor_id'],
                'sensor_type': row['sensor_type'],
                'location': [row['lat'], row['lon']],
                'date': row['timestamp'][:10],
                'data': [{}]
            }
            first_row = False

        if cnt_rows == 1:
            out['data'][-1]['start_time']: row['timestamp'][11:13]

        if (cnt_cols == event["matrix_size"]):
            cnt_cols = 0
            cnt_rows += 1
            if (cnt_rows == event["matrix_size"]):
                out['data'][-1]['end_time'] = row['timestamp'][11:13]
                out['data'][-1]['result'] = matrix_square(matrix)
                out['data'].append({})
                matrix = [[]]
                cnt_rows = 0
            else:
                matrix.append([])

        matrix[-1].extend([float(row['P1']), float(row['durP1']),
                           float(row['ratioP1']), float(row['P2']),
                           float(row['durP2']), float(row['ratioP2'])])
        cnt_cols += 6

    perf = time.perf_counter() - start

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({"output": out, "time": perf})
    }

def matrix_square(matrix):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        res.append([])
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            row = matrix[i]
            col = [r[j] for r in matrix]
            res[-1].append(0)
            for k in range(len(row)):
                res[i][j] += row[k] * col[k]
    return res
```

Comment: It can depend on your environment settings. How much memory do the Lambdas have? How it differs from your local machine?

Comment: Both Lambdas have been executed with the same memory allocated. I have executed them for various amounts of memory, and the results are similar for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

In lambda whenever you try to run function . aws automatically assign resources to your function on the first time base on your function requirement so that's the reason for that.
And this resources remain there for some time so there may be a case when you run fuction second time it will take less time then take time before.

Comment: The execution of the code is timed inside the function, so the allocation of the function, with its eventual cold start, and the environment setup are not regarded in the time returned by the function.